# In what kinds of environments, or in what situations, could a metal like Skarilium occur naturally?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, materials, metals

This will probably be the last time I refine this question.

Either way, here’s the notes for this refined version of the question:

- First, Skarilium now weighs 3,200 Kilograms per Cubic Meter and also has a melting point of 4,700 degrees Celsius.
- Second, Skarilium is the ‘evolved’ form of an alloy of [Specium](https://ultra.fandom.com/wiki/Spacium), Titanium, Cobalt, and Carbon.
- Third, Specium is a crystalline mineral that turns into plasma when exposed to Earth-like atmospheric conditions and is found in abundance on Mars and a variety of other planets.
- Fourth, an evolved form, in the context of this world’s chemistry, is an element that is formed from the elements in a compound becoming truly merged, which can take anywhere from a few months to several minutes depending on the elements that comprise the compound. How this process works is currently beyond me, but it’s only possible for it to work when one of the elements in the compound is one that has a specific, currently-unnamed property. In this case, Specium is the element with that property.

Now, given those notes, what kind of environments could Skarilium occur in naturally? Alternatively, what naturally-occurring events could cause Skarilium to be formed?

Comment: Can you explain how is this different from the other two questions you have already asked? You keep getting the same answers...

Comment: For the most part, I’m changing the details in each version of the question’s description to see if it changes what answers people come up with.

Comment: As I said, this is probably my last time changing it.

Answer (score 1):

**You will find it in craters.  You will find it in ice fields.**

There is stuff in this question I don't understand.  Rather than perseverate on that stuff, I will look at stuff I do understand and logic it out.

/Second, Skarilium is the ‘evolved’ form of an alloy of Specium, Titanium, Cobalt, and Carbon./  OK.  So we need those elements.

/ turns into plasma when exposed to Earth-like atmospheric conditions and is found in abundance on Mars and a variety of other planets/

OK.  Not going to find it on Earth, "found in abundance" on Mars.  How are Mars and Earth different?

Mars is a stony planet made of fundamentally the same part of the protoplanetary disk as Earth.  Long ago the two planets were more similar.  In current days the Martian atmosphere is different from Earth.  So if these materials are abundant on Mars currently, they must have arrived after Mars was formed and after it became different from Earth.  They arrived recently.

Considering only natural occurrences (no alien transports!), the stuff in question must have arrived on Mars as meteorites.

Do meteorites have the required materials in them?  **Yes.**
[Near-Earth asteroids: Metals occurrence, extraction, and fabrication](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991rnes.nasaR..22W%2F/abstract)

> Near-earth asteroids occur in three principle types of orbits: Amor,
> Apollo, and Aten. Amor asteroids make relatively close (within 0.3 AU)
> approaches to the earth's orbit, but do not actually overlap it.
> Apollo asteroids spend most of their time outside the earth's orbital
> path, but at some point of close approach to the sun, they cross the
> orbit of the earth. Aten asteroids are those whose orbits remain
> inside the earth's path for the majority of their time, with
> semi-major axes less than 0.1 AU. Near-earth orbit asteroids include:
> stones, stony-irons, irons, carbonaceous, and super-carbonaceous.
> Metals within these asteroids include: iron, nickel, cobalt, the
> platinum group,aluminum, titanium, and others.

Near Earth means near Mars so these will work.  How to find them after they hit Mars?

[The Meteorite Flux at the Surface of Mars](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1969PASP...81..399D&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_VIEW&classic=YES)

> ...the Martian surface is affoded varying degrees of protecton from
> impactng meterorites in the mass  range 10 grams to 1 metric ton.
> Meteorites with masses breater than 1 metric ton are lttel affected by
> passage through the atmosphere while meteroite of ~10 grams mass and
> less are completely decelerated by the Martian atmosphere and impact
> the Martian surface with terminal free fall velocties.

So you could look for big craters on the theory that big incoming meteorites will be at the bottom.  The substance in queston has a high melting point and so might survive the impact as a solid, though probably dispersed in fragments.  You could sort material excavated from these craters mechanically in a vibrating hopper, like panning for gold.

The other place to look would be the Martian ice caps.  Antarctica is a good place to find meteorites on Earth because they are easy to see.  It may be that ice flows can concentrate meteorites of certain types.  That could also be the case on Mars and other planets with ice fields.

[A potential hidden layer of meteorites below the ice surface of Antarctica](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10679)